# How to avoid js issue after installing new modules

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery, conflict

Although `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` is included in the head, installing new module can make js problem in other 3rd-party module. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should make sure that you have connected only one jQuery library, because third-party modules usually connects their own jQuery library, which is not necessary.

Second, if you are using the expression

`var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`

you need to make sure that all the modules are using alias `$j` instead of `$` to call jQuery. I would recommend you to use more simple structure after connecting jQuery library: `$.noConflict();` and use alias `$`.

Comment: Considering the code in ../d1/search.phtml---> <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="itellaSmartPost" id="s_method_itellaSmartPost"<?php if("itellaSmartPost"===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio"/>  and the code in /d1/search/result.phtm --> function updatePointValue(e) {
            var pointValue = $('smartpost_select_point').getValue();
          $(s_method_itellaSmartPost).value = pointValue; ....still I get the error undefind varibale for "s_method_itellaSmartPost" in IE ! Do you think it's due to conflict issu?

Comment: @Zinat We believe that it isn't connected with jQuery conflict, if you don't see this problem in other browsers.